# Backpressure when using interval

Tags: rx-java2, backpressure

I have this RxJava2 flowable

```
private val pulseFlowable = Flowable
   .interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
```

and this subscriber

```
pulseFlowable
   .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
   .subscribe(
      object : Subscriber<Long> {
         override fun onSubscribe(subscription: Subscription) {
            pulseSubscription = subscription
         }

         override fun onNext(long: Long?) {
            onPulse()
         }

         override fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
            Timber.e("onError")
         }

         override fun onComplete() {
            Timber.d("onComplete")
         }
      }
   )
```

It produces a `MissingBackPressureException`, which I "sort of" understand: Since I'm subscribing and observing on the same scheduler, I initially thought maybe backpressure would not occur, but maybe that was a misconception.

When I change the flowable to

```
private val pulseFlowable = Flowable
   .interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .onBackpressureLatest()
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
```

I no longer get an exception, but neither is onNext called. Why is that?

Comment: You did not request anything in `Subscriber.onSubscribe`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm moving from RxJava 1 to RxJava2, so apparently there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/docs/Backpressure-(2.0).md